# How to use PHPMailer via Composer on FTP

Tags: php, ftp, phpmailer, composer-php

i have started making my own site where i want to use [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)!.First of all i installed PHPMailer via Composer(cmd) on my desktop then used localhost to run my page where the PHPMailer was running just fine.I then tried to just transfer my page files and files that were generated in there from PHPMailer (those are:**vendor** directory ,**composer.json**,**composer.lock**) to FTP.When i tried running it on live page it didn't work and threw Error:

```
Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/www/sites/0/site25740/public_html/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php' 
(include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/local/zend/share/ZendFramework/library') in
 /www/sites/0/site25740/public_html/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 12
```

I think that my problem is that i generated those files into my desktop directory and therefore they are not working on live page.
Is there any way to maybe generate those files on my FTP server or maybe changing the structure of those files to work on live page?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please check your FTP server, if `vendor` directory, `composer.json` and `composer.lock` exist. Due to whatever reason `vendor` directory is either missing or is not in the correct location (`/public_html/vendor`)

Comment: In case you have, don't use a full, absolute path to your vendor folder. Your code should typically look like `require 'vendor/autoload.php';`, just a short relative path - then it will work wherever you run it.

Comment: All [files](https://ctrlv.cz/4e91)are on FTP server ,and the code is written exactly as you Synchro typed.

Comment: One more thing to look for would be, possible interruptions in FTP upload. Delete the vendor directory and this time upload a zipped version then extract upon successful upload.

Comment: I tried tho for some reason i cant extract from the file when i am on FTP server (i am using total commander for an FTP access)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use SSH not FTP.

Once you SSH into your server, you can run the `composer install` command to install dependencies the same as you have on your desktop.

[Edit] An FYI - Yes, we can upload the vendor folder.  Composer is a deployment tool.   Uploading a vendor folder is NOT using a deployment tool.

If I am deploying 100 applications - and uploading 50mb of dependencies 100 times from a branch office on a cable/dsl ... how fast & efficient is that?  If we offload that 50mb download to the server, how fast is that?

We have an option to do deployments wrong, or to do deployments properly.

I do not condone doing it wrong.   **It's clearly an option, however it is wrong.**

Comment: Or... You can upload the `vendor` directory, `composer.json` and `composer.lock` generated locally via FTP. Its all the same..

Comment: Uploading the vendor folder is not using composer.   That is not using the deployment tool as it is intended.

Comment: I get your pointing but Intented or not, the question is related to him uploading the files via FTP so IMO answerers should stick to OP's situation. There are lots of hosting environments out there where shell access isn't available!!!

Comment: It's been a very long time since I worked with one of those types of servers or have even seen one.  I didn't notice "no SSH access" anywhere in the post.  The question is very trivial in nature.  From that context - one could assume that SSH may not have been tried.  ( also ; I can't post comments ... or else I would have posted a comment.  That I can post answers but not post comments ... (??? Oh, hello StackOverflow; UX Much ???)

Comment: @KasemO Composer is NOT a deployment tool. Composer's maintainers does not recommend using it as a deployment tool.

Comment: i tried using this method however when i connect to the SSH i need to install composer and there is an error when i use 'wget https://getcomposer.org/installer' **FatalFatal: no entropy gathering module detected
Aborted**

Comment: @rob006 - as a "deployment" tool for the whole deploy ... it's part of the toolkit.Try one of the following: 
yum (Centos, RHEL family):  sudo yum install rng-tools 
apt (Ubuntu, Debian family):   apt-get install rng-tools

Comment: @Boris - my last comment was a bit messy.  

Error says you're missing a system RNG component.  Try one of the following: 

`yum (Centos, RHEL family):  sudo yum install rng-tools`

`apt (Ubuntu, Debian family):  sudo apt-get install rng-tools`

Comment: @KasemO I don't get your point, but even composer maintainers discourage from using composer on production server: https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/5367#issuecomment-220931565. So if there is a wrong way of doing deployment, you've described it in your answer as a "right" way...

Comment: @rob006 Point taken.  When I think "deployment" ; I think - fresh, bare metal getting set up as an app.   When I think "release", I think update of code (eg, prod release).   So, the disconnect I'm causing may simply be my phrasing.  As part of the initial setup process of the prod server, however --- for my team, the first run is acceptable.   Like the contributor mentioned "should not" ; but doesn't mean "can not".

Last off ; in initial setup & deployment of a prod app ... it's not even production yet!   It's a system that's still getting set up.